# Предложение: "И долго, с удивлением ребёнка, слежу полёты паутинок.". Почему "с удивлением ребенка" выделено запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

Учебник русского языка 8 класс, Ладыженская. Упражнение 187.

Answer (score 1):

В самом упражнении, как я понимаю, запятыми оборот **«с удивлением ребёнка»** не выделен. Требуется списать «восстановленный текст, расставляя пропущенные запятые».

Правило, по которому этот оборот **может** быть выделен запятыми, звучит так:

> **§ 74.** Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных надежей с предлогами, обособляются для попутного пояснения
> или **смыслового выделения**. Такое обособление факультативно…
>
> http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121

Ключевые слова в этом правиле: **такое обособление факультативно.**